# Final Cut Pro X Sharing to DVD 66% error? Slideshow compression?

Tags: video-editor, editing, conversion, final-cut-pro-x

I created a Slideshow in Final Cut Pro X.  I need to burn a DVD, I need to upload to YOUTUBE and I need to put on a jump drive.  I can export to Master File, however when I try to burn to DVD it only burns to 66% and stops.  I tried to "Add" background before burn to get it work to no avail.  The Slideshow is majority photos with very small small video at the end.  Specs are 720/42:22 minutes/42.4GB.  I just downloaded Wondershare video converter and feel perhaps I got ripped as it it stating conversion to 3.1gb will is taking 200 minutes.  I need help.  Any suggestions on how I can get this to burn to DVD, bypass 66% error, or compress smaller?

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity Monitor. I found that every time share (from fcpx) hangs @ 66% the app "DSPPublishing Server" wasn't responding. Look down the list of active Process Names and manually terminate it. This should allow Create DVD to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info!  I didn't have the app "DSPPublishing Server" in my Activity Monitor.  Instead I force quit Create DVD, through the Activity Monitor.  This seemed to solve the problem for me.  It restarted and finished the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Manually force quiting "DSPPublishing Server" was exactly the case for me. I force quit it and my DVD's burn successfully, thank you!

I've had to delete this on several occasions, not sure why I have to keep doing this, but I'm satisfied that at least there is something that does the trick now. I can burn short DVD's no issues, but once I'm burning larger files such as 1.41 gb and higher, I have to go through this process.

Comment: Unfortunately the app "DSPPublishing Server" does not
exist on my iMAC running FCPX.
DVD exporting jams at 66% .. there seems to be no cure ..
Only a problem with larger files (3gb .. 1hr 20 mins)